# Sqlite and Windows RT incompatibility issues

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8, windows-runtime, monogame

I have been working on a two player air hockey kind of game for windows RT devices using monogame, Apart from gaming logic I recently integrated sqlite for winRT in my app so that players could be able to save their scoreboard, view recent scores and share them on social networks. But with this Integration I started running into problems.

before explaining the problem Let me make you aware of my PC and target device architectures.

**The machine on which I am developing and testing is Windows 8 pro with 64 bit x64 based processor.**

**And the target machine is Windows RT 32 bit os, ARM based Processor.**

Now when I set the target platform of my app as "ANY CPU" and then try deploying my app I get an error which reads:

**Error 1   The processor architecture of the project being built "Any CPU" is not supported by the referenced SDK "SQLite.WinRT, Version=3.8.2". Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project (in visual studio this can be done through the Configuration Manager) to one of the architectures supported by the SDK: "x86, x64, ARM". Pong**

Now I set the target platform as ARM then again I am in an error which says

**Error 6   Error : DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. Windows cannot install package da981e37-1c3c-4614-8c85-40485aa9e4a8 because the package requires architecture ARM, but this computer has architecture x64. (0x80073cf3)   Pong**

then I set the target to x86. This makes the game run normally on my PC but the package installation on target device fails with this option.

Now finally I am left with x64 as the target. This also runs well on my system, also the package gets easily installed on target machine. But it just shows me a black screen for long(Note that it is not a crash!).

I know I might be doing silly somewhere. But I am stuck on this from a long time.

Its a long note, But its only so that I could make you well aware with my problem.

Please provide the answer to the problem.

Your Suggestions are always appreciated :) Thanks.

Comment: I believe SQLite references 32 or 64 bit DLL's compiled in C or C++ meaning it's not a pure .NET DLL. This will cause issues on ARM processors unless those DLL's can be recompiled to target ARM which may not be possible (or at least, a lot of work).

Comment: okay, That is something tedious! Then how do we integrate database in a game? I mean if its difficult for us to make sqlite work in such conditions then what would be the perfect way to maintain a db in a game?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to Deploy or Debug in your Development machine, set the target Platform as "x86". When you want to deploy or debug in your RT device, change the target platform to "ARM".

You cannot deploy an app which targets "x86", or "x64" to an ARM device.

Also the "Microsoft C++ Runtime Package" dll will not allow you Build with the configuration of "Any CPU".

Comment: I am doing in the same way but before the app gets deployed on the target machine the app package is first created on the machine I am using for development purpose. And I am unable to create an ARM package in my development machine.

Comment: You need to configure the build package each time you create package for different devices. Have a look at [here](http://tinypic.com/r/ixgth2/8). I'm able to create one with SQLite targeting ARM.